# Append parameters to createUrl() Yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I try to wrote ajax request in Yii 1 with jQuery. In my URL i try to append value of id attribute of my link, but I cant do that. Here is my code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('vot', "
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-register-member').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '" . $this->createUrl('cre/register/124'). "',
        });
    });
});
```

");
I need to put my parametr where 124 is situated... I try put there somethink like:

```
$(this).attr('id'); but I get  500 error
```

Comment: have you tried like this?
$this->createUrl('cre/register/$(this).attr(\'id\');'). "',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope it will work

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('vot', "
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.js-register-member').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '" . $this->createUrl('cre/register/') . "'  + id ,
            });
        });
    });
");
```

Comment: hm....i didn work when i go to second page (gridView)... all scripts there but preventDefault not work andrequest dont sends...